# Server side role access routing for angular JS in MEAN

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am working on MEAN stack and my head insist on incorporating server side role authorization for routing.
To put it simple, the solution must fit the need in the way that **there is no way the user can trick the browser to access the page** unless a proper access token is provided.
I have search tutorial online, and all of the solution provided could still be bypass by tricking the browser with modification in code.

Example:
1) User have access token in cookies. 
2) Client Side/Server Side decrypt the access token and identify user role
3) The user role is return to the logic for roles accessibility.

At the end of the day, user could still trick the browser by:
1) removing/replacing logic for the pieces of code that return user role
2) replacing the return value with specific user role to access it.

How could this be avoided?

```
$routeProvider.when('/admin/index', {
        controller: 'AdminIndex',
        templateUrl: 'AdminIndex.html',
        access: {
            roles: ['Admin']
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client is entirely under the control of the user. You need to use the access token to determine what roles the user has **on the server** and limit access to the data needed to populate the pages there.

Don't worry about the user being able to access the Admin page, just worry about allowing them to get the data that only admins should have access to and about accepting requests (as authorised) from them to endpoints that change things on the server.

Comment: This is what I currently implementing now, using access token to determine user role, but still user have plenty of way to access the page by tricking the browser without the need of access token. I am trying to convince my head that it is not possible but I need a firm backup for it. Or else I would be in trouble if he manage to implement it when I say it is not possible.

Comment: @stackdisplay — If you perform the test on the *server* then it doesn't matter what the user tricks the browser into thinking, it will try to load the admin page, fail to get the data (from the server) it needs to display anything sensitive on it, and the problem will be gone.

Comment: Hi we are well aware that at the end of the day the sensitive data will not be display but my head insist that it would be better that the page won't appear/flicker at all. So, the only way is to do in server side. But is this possible to be done with MEAN?

Comment: Short of not providing access to the bits of JavaScript which set up the client side routes for those pages, and those bits of template that are used to make up the pages (which would be a lot of complication (and risk of introducing bugs) to stop harmless hacking from giving a poor experience), no. You can't control what goes on in the user's browser. It belongs to the user.